# Ubuntu Server 16.04 Squid Proxy authentication with 2 NIC setup

Tags: 16.04, server, authentication, squid

I have an Ubuntu proxy running server 16.04, squid 3.5.12 and NCSA. The server has two NICs, one connected to internet router, eno1 with IP 192.168.1.2/24 and another connected to client LAN, eno2 with IP 192.168.2.1/24. When I configure proxy settings on client machine, the browser requests login credentials but when I choose auto detect proxy settings, the user browses internet with nothing even being captured in access.log. Primarily, I want users who bypass proxy settings not to be able to browse internet, that's my number one objective. Here is my priority list:

1. All client users must be authenticated when browsing internet – username and password (a must)
2. Users who bypass proxy settings on their browser must not browse internet (a must)

NB: ASSIST ME WITH OBJECTIVE 2

In terms of iptables, I really have nothing and would be happy if any person who chooses to explain do so bearing in mind that I am running Ubuntu 16.04. I now know how to save iptables but to have the ones that can achieve my objective is the main problem. I have literally commented out everything I had done in rc.local as it is not achieving anything.

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# Gre tunnel interface
#auto wccp0
#iface wccp0 inet manual
#       pre-up ip tunnel add wccp0 gre remote 10.10.101.2 local 192.168.0.4 dev eno1 ttl 255

# The primary network interface
auto eno1
iface eno1 inet static
        address 192.168.1.2
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 192.168.1.0
        broadcast 192.168.1.255
        gateway 192.168.1.1
        # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
        dns-nameservers 192.168.0.5
        dns-search hit.ac.zw

#Secondary interface
auto eno2
iface eno2 inet static
        address 192.168.2.1
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 192.168.2.0
        gateway 192.168.2.1
#save ip tables
pre-up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.up.rules
```

Squid configuration:

```
auth_param basic program /usr/lib/squid/basic_ncsa_auth /etc/squid/passwd
auth_param basic children 5
auth_param basic realm Systems Admin
auth_param basic credentialsttl 2 hours
auth_param basic casesensitive off
acl blocked_sites url_regex -i "/etc/squid/blocked_sites"
acl ncsa_users proxy_auth REQUIRED

#acl blocked_sites url_regex -i "/etc/squid/blocked_sites"
acl localnet src 192.168.1.0/24
acl localnet src 192.168.2.0/24
#acl lan src 192.168.1.0/24

acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80          # http
acl Safe_ports port 21          # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443         # https
acl Safe_ports port 70          # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210         # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280         # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488         # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591         # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777         # multiling http
acl CONNECT method CONNECT

http_port 3128

http_access deny !ncsa_users
http_access deny ncsa_users blocked_sites

#http_access deny blocked_sites
# Deny requests to certain unsafe ports
http_access deny !Safe_ports
#http_access deny localnet
#http_access deny lan
# Deny CONNECT to other than secure SSL ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports

# Only allow cachemgr access from localhost
http_access allow localhost manager
http_access deny manager
```

IP-tables:

```
#MY IPTABLE - it has been changed several times i no longer have original
    *filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [231:24245]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [205:45205]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [155:73325]
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 192.168.2.1/24 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3128 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 192.168.2.0/24 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
COMMIT
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [1001:61764]
:INPUT ACCEPT [211:12736]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [10:814]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [719:45963]
-A PREROUTING -i eno2 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3128
-A PREROUTING -i eno1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.2:3128
COMMIT
```

Routing table:

```
root@proxy:~# route -n
    Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eno1
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eno1
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eno2
```

Route Print From Client Machine

```
IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.2.1      192.168.2.2    276
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
      192.168.2.0    255.255.255.0         On-link       192.168.2.2    276
      192.168.2.2  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.2.2    276
    192.168.2.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.2.2    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       192.168.2.2    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.2.2    276
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.2.1  Default
===========================================================================
```

[image: network diagram]

Comment: What is your iptables rules? Is the ubuntu machine a router in addition to a proxy server?

Comment: its just a proxy. l will be grateful if you can prepare for me in a clear manner iptables rules that can achieve especially objective 1 and 2. As for the ones I have its as good as l don't have anything since l have been messing them trying to achieve the above goals.

Comment: Can you include the output of `ping -c 3 8.8.8.8` on one of the clients?

Comment: ping -c refused to work but l can ping google. l have also posted the poor iptables l have above

Comment: If you can ping google they obviously have a route to the internet that bypasses the proxy. What does the routing table on the clients show?

Comment: Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eno1
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eno1
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eno2
root@proxy:~#                                                                                    View it above where l am posting with code editor

Comment: That is not from one of the clients. That's from the proxy server. In addition, please [edit] your question to include content, and use the {} button to get code formatting.

Comment: 14 days after asking a question and still no solution for me????